# Best way to extract a table from a website (ESPN) into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, power-query

I have a page in my ESPN.com league that has a lot of data I'd like to extract to Excel. I've included a screenshot below.

I've tried simply copy and pasting but the player images get in the way. I've also tried web grabbing Chrome extensions like Blackbox (which will let you highlight an area and paste values), however, it's not clean, you can only do one column at a time and you can't scroll down (the page has about 500 names).

I've also tried to go through Excel and do a Get Data from web query but I can't seem to navigate all the way to that page within Excel.

I know this is a silly-ish ask but it's genuinely bothering me that I can't think of a good way to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: this isn't imported - this is just an option to amend their standard valuations

Comment: If you can use Phython, you can use Phython to crawl data on web pages. Excel only has the Get Data from web query feature.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Open Excel

2.) Navigate to Data tab

3.) Find "From Web"

4.) Paste your URL

[image: excel-web-import]

5.) Do some clicking according to the common sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little, simple userscript for [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) (might work also for other script managers). It can copy a HTML table.

I've no access to the exact page you showed, but it works on this one and also on plenty non ESPN.
https://fantasy.espn.com/football/mockdraftlobby

So, here it is:
https://gist.github.com/JakubMarcinkowski/17556651b07329b7753974cc222be672

Click "Raw" on the top-right corner and install. Refresh the page, click on Tampermonkey icon on the toolbar and then "Copy table for spreadsheet".

The most important code is here:

```
tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');
table = tables[0];
GM_setClipboard(table.outerHTML, 'html');
```

I used GM_setClipboard for no permissions problems and easy HTML copying for spreadsheet pasting.